# Elasticsearch: No filter registered for [geo_shape]]

Tags: json, elasticsearch, geospatial

I have a "counties" index, with county documents that resemble the following (extra polygon points ommitted for brevity):

```
{ "fips" : 1093,
  "location" : {
    "type" : "polygon",
    "coordinates" : [ [ [ -88.194525, 34.157699 ], [ -88.192128, 34.175351 ], ..., [ -88.194525, 34.157699 ] ] ]
  }
}
```

I have created a mapping for these counties:

```
"mappings" : {
    "county" : {
            "properties" : {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_shape"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then try to query these documents with a query like the following:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "geo_shape" : {
          "location" : {
            "shape" : {
              "type" : "envelope",
              "coordinates" : [[-87.17863946,41.57623478],[-87.17863846,41.57623578]]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}g
```

This returns the following error:

```
{[OQuTlmv0RdmC34MLnN8qHQ][counties][1]: SearchParseException[[counties][1]:  from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"geo_shape\":{\"location\":{\"shape\":{\"type\":\"envelope\",\"coordinates\":[[-87.17863946,41.57623478],[-87.17863846,41.57623578]]}}}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[counties] No   filter registered for [geo_shape]]; }]",
"status" : 400
```

}

I can't find any reference to a similar error when searching. I have tried this in filter and query forms, with similar errors. Using Elasticsearch 1.1.0.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: 1.1.0.  Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: I think you should open an issue with a full SENSE recreation.

Comment: File the issue on GitHub?

Comment: So, I only encounter this issue when using an "embedded" ES instance that runs within the same JVM as my application.  When I run it using an external instance, the query performs without error. Not sure how to continue troubleshooting this, as the embedded instance was only a convenience for the prototype.

Comment: Interesting... how do you query the embedded node? REST calls or Java api? I guess you already double checked the version of the embedded node is the right one?